# Odoo file upload with browser open file dialog

Tags: python, file-upload, odoo, openfiledialog

I created a smart button in my Odoo form.view with the following XML statement:

```
<div name="button_box" class="oe_right" position="inside">
    <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" name="upload_pictures" type="object" icon="fa-cloud-upload" string="Upload Pictures" />
</div>
```

And in the python class of my model I used the following definition to do something after clicking on the smart button.

```
@api.multi
def upload_pictures(self):
    ...
```

This works fine, but my question is now how can I start a browser popup "open file ..." after clicking on my smart button an process the selected files from the open file dialog in my python class definition?

Many thanks for your helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to implement a custom widget for this. object buttons trigger actions in server side not client side

Comment: Thanks for your information! Can you give me some further information how to implement a custom widget?

Comment: You can find more about widgets in the ofoocial documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html
also you may find some examples of odoo widgets in addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js

If you want just to upload a file you don't have to go through all of this you may use the binary field of odoo and the task is handled by odoo.

Comment: do you also know an example how to use a widget at clicking on a smart button?

Comment: you can take a look at the board module there are the reset and change layout buttons